# Allowing user to read only parts of NTFS filesystem

Tags: gnome, filesystems, windows, ntfs, ntfs-3g

After installing ntfs-3g I have an option in nautilus to mount a Windows directory but I need to give root password. While I have no objection to giving root password I would prefer to be restricted to permission of corresponding Windows user (i.e. disallowing modification of system files). Is is easily achievable or do I need to post feature request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There IS a way to recognize Windows permissions on a ntfs-3g mount. You have to create a user-mapping file. See [here](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/user-mapping/).

This can be done from within Linux too, with the `ntfs-3g.usermap` utility. See the manual pages for `mount.ntfs-3g` and `ntfs-3g.usermap`. (I use Fedora 14.)

EDIT: I don't know what effect enabling this will have on Nautilus' mount feature. Me, I like to mount the partitions in `/etc/fstab` and leave it at that.

Comment: It uses default i.e. `.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` with respective to NTFS partition.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I did not try this, so it may or may not work; I don't have an NTFS volume around.

Mount the whole FS with permissions that prevent target users from reading it.

Mount a directory of the resulting tree at an accessible mount point with `mount --bind` and subsequent `mount --o remount` with different `uid` and `umaks` that allow target users to read it.

Comment: I meant rather a automated solution. I rarely access the NTFS partition (since I hardly have anything on it - however I sometimes need to use Windows).

Comment: If you are only interested in the same NTFS folders every time, e.g. 'Documents and Settings', you can wrap this logic into a simple script, or even an udev script if your NTFS drives are portable.